# Set up shareable hawtio dashboard

Tags: hawtio

How to set up shareable common hawtio dashboard for camel applications in such a way that the dashboard is pre-populated. I've set hawtio.config.dir to a local file. If I access hawtio from a new browser, I've to always manually set up the dashbaord for first time, which is painful. How to get rid of this?

Questions
 - How to set up common hawtio dashboard which should work in a clustered environment?
 - Is there a way to export and upload dashboards in hawtio? like how kibana has.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JBoss Fuse, then it provides Fuse Fabric (fabric8) which has a distributed registry, that hawtio leverages. This allows to have shared dashboards, and a few other hawtio configurations. That registry is git based.

Therefore in standalone hawtio then this ought to be possible as well, if you startup hawtio to use a remote git repo

There is some details about the git configurations at:

- http://hawt.io/configuration/index.html

Another alternative is that you can use gist to share dashboard, so you can crete a gist, and then others can import the gist. But that would be a manual procedure.